# apply z-score to a list containing multiple tuples

Tags: python

Please help me. I started learning python. I am trying to do an exercise. I have a list. I want to apply a z-score to numeric values in the tuples and do not change the initial elements of the tuples. But as a result, every tuple repeats itself 3 times. what is the reason for repeating the same list 3 times? why the s, h, and y tuples are in one listen? I wrote the following code for this:

```
var= [('S', '10', '13','25','17','29', '30'), ('Y', '2','2.2', '2.7', '3','1', 1.8), ('H', '5.4', '2.1', '3.4','2','1.2', 2.37)]

column=[]
row=[]
for col in var:
    col = (list(col))
    row.append(col[0])
    col.pop(0)
    col = list(map(float, col))

    for rows in col:
        # print(row)
        # print(col)
        rows = (rows - np.mean(col)) / (np.std(col))
        row.append(rows)
    column.append(row)
print(column)
```

Comment: Please review and accept my edit to the question. Otherwise the code looks a bit confusing to those not aware of numpy library methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the modified version of your code: https://repl.it/repls/ImpoliteImpassionedVirtualmachine
Basically you are not resetting your list named row after z-score calculation is done for each tuple.

```
column=[] .  
row=[] 
for col in var:
    col = (list(col))
    row = []
    row.append(col[0])
    col.pop(0)
    col = list(map(float, col))
    for rows in col:
        # print(row)
        #print(rows)
        rows = (rows - np.mean(col)) / (np.std(col))
        row.append(rows)
    column.append(row)
print(column)
```

Comment: I am grateful to you. Thank you very much for your reply @Sagar Ruchandani